# Django filter form field by Foreign Key

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to filter a form selection so that a user can only select players from certain competitions. I have changed the `_init_` function in the form as follows but nothing changes

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from matchdaycentremodel.models import FantasyTeam
from playerteamstats.models import Player

class FantasySeasonForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FantasyTeam

    def _init_(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(FantasySeasonForm,self)._init_(**kwargs)
        self.fields['player1'].queryset = playerteamstats.models.Player.objects.filter(team__competition__pk=2)
```

The relevant models are..

**models.py** (playerteamstats)

```
class Competition(models.Model):
    COMP_ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    season = models.ForeignKey(Season) #Foreign Key
    competition_id = models.IntegerField()
    competition_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    competition_code = models.CharField(max_length=6)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s (%s)' % (self.competition_name, self.season.season_id) #e.g. 'English Barclays Premier League (2014)'

class Team(models.Model):
    team_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    competition = models.ForeignKey(Competition) #Foreign Key
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.team_name

class Player(models.Model):
    player_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team) #Foreign Key
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.player_name
```

**models.py** (matchdaycentremodel)

```
class FantasyTeam(models.Model):
    FANTASY_TEAM_ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    player1 = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name='player1')
    player2 = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name='player2')
    player3 = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name='player3')
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def entry(request):
    fantasyTeamForm = FantasySeasonForm() #Form to store each player in the fantasy team

    if request.method == 'POST':
        fantasyTeamForm = FantasySeasonForm(request.POST or None)   
        fantasyTeamForm.fields
        if fantasyTeamForm.is_valid():           
            fantasyTeamForm.save()            
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/season/entrysuccess') #page on success


    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = fantasyTeamForm

    return render_to_response('entry.html', args, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

How do I filter the form's player1 so that it can only be selected from a certain competition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `init` is defined as `def _init_` whereas it should be `def __init__` (double underscores)

Also, as crhodes mentions, you should be doing something like:

```
self.fields['player1'].queryset = Player.objects.filter(team__competition_id=2)
```

The reason this was not raising an exception was, these lines of code were never executed.

Answer (score 1):

If your import statements are correct, should

```
self.fields['player1'].queryset = playerteamstats.models.Player.objects.filter(team__competition__pk=2)
```

not be

```
self.fields['player1'].queryset = Player.objects.filter(team__competition__pk=2)
```

Comment: Still makes no difference, just shows all the players :'(